# different data types in ArcMap field calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, field-calculator

I would like to run the following pre logic code in the Arcmap field calculator:

```
def calc(f, fn, f1, f1n)

f= str(f)
f1 = str(f1)

f = f.replace("  ", "")
fn = fn.replace("  ", "")
f1 = f1.replace("  ", "")
f1n = f1n.replace("  ", "")

if f+fn == f1+f1n:
    return "IDENTICAL"
elif f == f1:
    return "Same no diff. street"
elif fn == f1n
    return "diff no. same street"
else
    return "different"
```

where f and f1 are double and fn and f1n are string type fields. When I run it I get a syntax error for line 1. Could anyone help me spot it? This is the command

```
calc(!ADDRNMBR!, !ADDRNAME!, !ADDRNMBR_1!, !ADDRNAME_1!)
```

Comment: `elif fn == f1n:` and `else:` - dont forget the colons - and after `def calc(...)`

Comment: yes I fixed that... now I'm getting indentation errors though. What are the indentation rules for Python?

Comment: ok - i assumed indentation was there, so i edited your question accordingly. there are docs on indentation [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation). Basically because python does not use 'end' statements for loops or functions - you indent to form classes, functions, if statements, loops, etc..

Comment: @fluidmotion I rolled back the edits because I believe the formatting is part of the OP's coding problem.

Comment: thanks @Aaron  - i didn't realize that initially. good to roll-back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so if it helps - i think it would look something like -

```
def calc(f, fn, f1, f1n): #note colon here
    # everything within function is indented
    f = str(f)
    f1 = str(f1)

    f = f.replace("  ", "")
    fn = fn.replace("  ", "")
    f1 = f1.replace("  ", "")
    f1n = f1n.replace("  ", "")

    if f+fn == f1+f1n:
        # each return of if or elif is indented
        return "IDENTICAL"
    elif f == f1:
        return "Same no diff. street"
    elif fn == f1n: #and colon here
        return "diff no. same street"
    else: # and colon here
        return "different"
```

Comment: thank you that worked and also clarified the use of indents within python

Comment: It may help to write your pre-logic code in a Python interpreter first (like IDLE, which comes pre-packaged with ArcGIS Desktop), which takes care of indentation and colon errors, rather than using the plain-text field in the Field Calculator box. It's hard to find errors in plain-text boxes when writing code.